# Resize event remove and re-add element in DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove and re-add element of my DOM which depends on the screen size but just can't get it to work.

Here is what I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="hideit">Some text</div>
```

**JS:**

```
require(['jquery'], function(){
    jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
            var childhtml = jQuery("#hideit").detach();
            if(window.innerWidth < 990) {
            jQuery("#hideit").remove();
            }
            if(window.innerWidth > 990){
            jQuery("#hideit").append(childhtml);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest CSS media rule for this. You don't need to use jQuery and can achieve the same effect. You can read more here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: That will only `hide` the element and not remove it from DOM... And I need to remove it for the rest of my code to work properly.. :/

Comment: In that case I'd suggest changing how the rest of your code works. Media queries is *by far* the best way to do this, for a variety of reasons, not least support and performance.

Comment: So the rest of the code can check if the element is visible or not instead of  checking if the element is in the DOM.

Comment: So this is something that can't be achieved this way?

Comment: Why are you using `detach` *and* `remove`? Detach alone should do.

Comment: I tried both, however, the `deatch()` leaves the element in the dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/969/)**.

You've to clone it first then you could remove/add it when the user resize :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var hideit = jQuery("#hideit").clone(true);

  jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (innerWidth < 990) {
      jQuery("#hideit").detach();
    } else if (innerWidth > 990) {
      if (!jQuery("#hideit").length) {
        jQuery("body").append(hideit);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hideit">Some text</div>
```

Comment: The div won't show when you resize the window back.

Comment: When I resize it back, the element is still gone :/

Comment: Then you've to change the `990`

Comment: Try it using the live fiddle with `500` and you can see it working. https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/962/

Comment: `detach()` still leaves the code in the DOM, can I use `remove()` and ahve the same effect?

Comment: Hymmm it still leaves it in the DOM or "memory" , could it be because of the `clone()`?

Comment: Where you see it ?

Comment: Check this update that check in every pixel move if the element exist in the DOM or not https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/971/

Comment: Will it make a difference if the `<div id="hideit">` have more elements inside?

Comment: I GOT IT!! Your function was set to `500` and I was checking it aganist `990` like in question... Stupid me... Upvote and accept! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry my bad too, Glad I could help, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
  var el = jQuery("#hideit").detach();
  jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth < 990) {
      jQuery("#hideit").remove();
    }
    if(window.innerWidth > 990){
      el.appendTo('body'); // or other place
    }
  });
});
```